# Angular2 ngFor collapses always the same <tr>

Tags: jquery, angular, angularjs, ngfor

A rookie web developer here.

I used `*ngFor` to create my `<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details">`.
What i experience is that clicking on a row always collapses the same `div` and not the one matching to it.

Probably has to be something with the fact they all get the same id (?)

What am i doing wrong and how can I achieve what I'm looking for?

## CODE:

```
<template let-transaction ngFor [ngForOf]="accountTransactions">
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details">
        <td>{{transaction.time}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.description}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.amount}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.currency}}</td>
    </tr>
    <div class="container collapse" id="details">
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried playing with the index of the current iterated object and placing it for the `data-target` and for the `id` of the collapsible `<div>` like that:

```
<template let-transaction ngFor [ngForOf]="accountTransactions" let-i="index">
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#'+i">
        <td>{{transaction.time}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.description}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.amount}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.currency}}</td>
    </tr>
    <div class="container collapse" [attr.id]="i">
```

Hope it'll help somebody